# Fix minimum size of 3D globe cesium

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I want to fix the minimum size of 3D globe such as if user decreases the size through mouse it should not decrease beyond some fixed value.

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer("cesiumContainer", {

animation: false,

timeline: false

});
```

[Sandcastle Link](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=bY7BasMwDIZfRfjUQrDZtXXDoNfBDoOefFETdROT7WIrKd3Yuy9Jdxhbdfs/fb/QiAVGpgsV2EGiC+yp8hDtYWGrYLol73NS5EQlmAY+QwoJE0dUzmkDJ5RKzQyVI8mk/bAZfa23pjG+6lWoDQmWeeR4zkVhKLKy1inFs6BSdceheye1Xa3r7U327nfV9zwC97s7f0EnWOu0OQ0iL/xBwbTeTf6/qmTsOb0+j1QEr7P29tA+3aC11rsp3m9qznLE8ufyNw)

Any help is highly appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer("cesiumContainer");  // plus whatever options

viewer.scene.screenSpaceCameraController.maximumZoomDistance = 1e8;
```

The value `1e8` here is the maximum number of meters that the camera is allowed to travel away from the focus point (typically the center of the Earth).  You can try `1e7` or `1e9` to adjust it.

Answer (score 1):

```
viewer.scene.screenSpaceCameraController.minimumZoomDistance = 6378137;
viewer.scene.screenSpaceCameraController.maximumZoomDistance = 6378137 * 2;
```